# maui: cant find "handler" inside mauiprogram.cs

Tags: maui

I am trying to registre my own handler like this:

```
    builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(collection =>
    {
        //#if __ANDROID__
        handlers.AddHandler<CollectionView, CustomCollectionViewHandler>();
        //#endif
    });
```

This is in MauiProgram.cs file.

handler however doesnt exist.
What AM i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create?view=net-maui-8.0#register-the-handler)

```
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
        {
            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Video), typeof(VideoHandler));
        });
```

since you are using `collection` instead of `handlers` in the lambda, you would then use

```
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(collection =>
        {
            collection.AddHandler(typeof(Video), typeof(VideoHandler));
        });
```